# Display column headers that have been filtered in Excel

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions

I wish to be able to display a list of the filters that have been applied to data.

I have found a solution which, from the comments, appears to work at https://superuser.com/questions/436667/show-excel-column-filter-information-in-cells

I have copied the function:

```
Function CheckFilters(r As Range) As String

Set AWS = ActiveSheet
fstate = ""

If AWS.FilterMode Then
    c = AWS.AutoFilter.Filters.Count

    'go through each column and check for filters
    For i = 1 To c Step 1
       If AWS.AutoFilter.Filters(i).On Then
            fstate = fstate & r(i).Value & ", "
       End If
Next i

'removes the last comma
fstate = Left(fstate, Len(fstate) - 2) 
Else
    fstate = "NO ACTIVE FILTERS"
End If

CheckFilters = fstate

End Function
```

into a Module and copied the following formula into a cell on my spreadsheet:

```
=CheckFilters(A3:U3) & LEFT(SUBTOTAL(9,A5:A200),0)
```

The cell with the formula in displays a *#Value* error and when I try to filter the header, I receive a 'Variable not defined' error with `AWS =` highlighted in the VBA window.

I have tried removing the AWS element and used `ActiveSheet` through the function instead but I then received another 'Variable not defined' error with `fstate` highlighted.

I am unsure what to define 'fstate' as.

I would go back to the original post but I do not have sufficient rep to add a comment to reach out to the member that posted the solution.

Any help would be gratefully received!

EDIT - The original issue is resolved but I now have a 'Compile Error: Method or data member not found' message with `.FilterMode` highlighted in the `If AWS.FilterMode Then` line...

Reaching out for support to fix this part now :)

Thank you.

Comment: Would dimming your variables make it work? Try adding: Dim AWS as sheets, Dim fstate as string

Comment: Thanks JvdD, I thought I needed to define them but wasn't sure what as - that's solved that error. I have updated the question as I now have another error! Do you have anymore advice? Sorry - my VBA knowledge is gradually building but not securely enough to resolve errors!